# If $U_1,...,U_n$ are unif(0,1) , then is $(U_1,...,U_n)$ unif$[0,1]^n$?

Tags: uniform-distribution

Let $U_1,...,U_n$ be identicaly distributed random variable unif(0,1).

Consider random vector $U=(U_1,...,U_n)$.

How can I show that $U$ is distributed as unif$(0,1)^n$?

Intuitively, It is obvious.

Comment: Write the CDF of $U$ compare it with the one of unif$[0,1]^n$. Can you do that? Put that in your question please, and let me know if you get stuck after that.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F_i$ denote the distribution of $U_i$ (for each $i$) and let $F_*$ denote the distribution of $(U_1,\ldots,U_n)$. By definition, we have that $F_i(u_i)=u_i$ for every $u_i\in(0,1)$. Due to the independence property, we then have that $F_*(u_1,...,u_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n F_i(u_i)=\prod_{i=1}^n u_i$. This is all we need to show since the right-hand side is the distribution of the $n$-dimensional Uniform distribution.

Comment: The original problem statement does not say that the $U_i$ are independent.  The case $U_1=U_2=\cdots=U_n$ satisfies all the hypotheses, but not the conclusion.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I suppose I read the problem statement too quickly and just assumed that. But as you point out, the conclusion might not hold without independence. In fact, Sklar's theorem implies that the conclusion holds iff the components are mutually independent.